# ¿Como pasar un id a otra tabla?

Tags: php, html, laravel, phpmyadmin, laravel-blade

tengo que hacer un sistema para bibliotecas. Tengo una tabla "Libro" que se relaciona a "Prestamo". El id de libro se envía a prestamos para saber cual fue prestado, lo que necesito es que al prestar un libro me aparezca en la tabla "Libro" el id del "Prestamo". Ojalá pudieran darme una idea.
Estos son mis métodos para guardar las tablas.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $libro = new Libro();
    $libro->id = $request->id;
    $libro->titulo = $request->titulo;
    $libro->autor = $request->autor;
    $libro->no_prestamo = $request->no_prestamo;
    $libro->save();
}

public function store(Request $request)
{
    $prestamo= new Prestamo();
    $prestamo->no_prestamo = $request->no_prestamo;
    $prestamo->id_usuario = $request->id_usuario;
    $prestamo->fecha_prestamo = $request->fecha_prestamo;
    $prestamo->fecha_devolucion = $request->fecha_devolucion;
    $prestamo->id_libro = $request->id_libro;
    $prestamo->save();

}
```

Comment: Puedes agregar las tablas que creaste? Necesitas un elemento externo (foreignID). También puedes agregar los controladores? Es importante saber qué tipo de relación estás utilizando para entender en qué parte te estas atorando

Comment: ¿Qué sentido tiene meter en `Libro` el id del préstamo? `Libro` debe ser una entidad independiente, no debes hacerlo cargar con algo circunstancial, como es un préstamo. En el segundo fragmento de código ya tienes el id del libro, así debe ser y no al revés, metiendo en la entidad Libro el id del préstamo.

Comment: Pienso que podría pasarle el id del préstamo para saber si el libro lo tiene alguien y saber el numero de préstamo. Por eso lo tengo de esa manera.

Comment: Ya, pero para saber si el Libro lo tiene alguien no tienes que preguntarle al libro, sino a la entidad que controla los libros disponibles, que podría ser préstamo u otra entidad. Si en una clase o tabla que debe ser una entidad única (`Libro` en este caso) tú metes datos circunstanciales, estás haciendo a esa entidad inútil desde el punto de vista del modelo de datos. Un `Libro` sólo debe tener aquellas propiedades que **son propias a TODOS los libros** y nada más. Ese es el *quid* de la cuestión aquí.